# haskell Function taking 2 arguments returns function which takes one argument?

Tags: haskell

Consider this code:

```
type Graph = (Char, Function) 
type Function = Char -> Int 
doThingsWithGraph :: Graph -> String
func :: Function 
graph :: Graph

main = do  x <- getChar
           y <- getChar
           let graph = (x, func)
           putStrLn $ doThingsWithGraph graph
```

The implementation of `doThingsWithGraph` does not matter for now. Now the issue here is that the `func`'s output also depends on the second char I am getting from the user, but I have no idea how to pass it on to it. I can't pass it as an argument because func is implemented by third party and I can't change the type. So if haskell had global variables and `y` was one the `func`'s implementation would look something like this:

```
func char 
       |isDigit char = digitToInt char + digitToInt y
       |otherwise    = digitToInt y
```

This obviously doesn't work because `func` has no idea what `y` is, but that's the idea of what it should do. So `y` is the value that I need somehow to let `func` know about (it is the one I'm getting from user in the second line of `main`). I can't do `getLine` inside `func` because that won't be consistent with data type which I can't change (part of the large framework). Any ideas? Maybe some helper function can replace `func` in `let graph = (x, func)`and then return the function of type Function? This is just a guess..

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "`func` is implemented by third party".  Do you mean "I want third parties to be able to implement such `func`s"?

Comment: Sorry I was misleading, I meant that "graph" is already implemented in a framework I am working with and requires a function of type Function as a second argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your user generating `func` can simply implement a function like `Char -> Function` and hand you that instead of a raw `Function` with the promise that you'll give them the second char from input as that first argument.

Indeed, this is a very natural thing in a language with no globals: you must state all the information you need in your function inputs. Anything else just won't work.

You'll end up with

```
doThingsWithGraph (x, makeFunc y)
```

When that gets burdensome, the Reader Monad can help.

Comment: So you are saying that I can make a function which takes one argument and returns a function which takes something else? If that's the case that is what I need. I just never wrote a function that returns a function before. Do you have any further tips how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. `makeFunc` would be of `Char -> Char -> Int` type, meaning you can either pass two `Char` arguments and get an `Int` or just one argument and get a `Char -> Int` function. No extra steps are needed.

Comment: @user2922609 That's exactly right! And a really common pattern in Haskell. It's strange at first, no doubt, but you can see all multi-parameter functions as being "applied one argument at a time". For instance if we have `add x y = x + y` then `add :: Int -> Int -> Int` and `add 2 :: Int -> Int` both being perfectly valid functions. This property is called "partial application".

Comment: See also http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying, which explains more about this technique of "functions returning functions".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "`func` is implemented by third party".  Do you mean "I want third parties to be able to implement such `func`s in a way that permits me to use them like this"?

If so, does

```
func :: Char -> Function
func y char 
       |isDigit char = digitToInt char + digitToInt y
       |otherwise    = digitToInt y
```

do the job?  This is also what J. Abrahamson is suggesting, I think.